# PHP post data to an HTTPS page

Tags: php, post, https

I have a https page named user.php that gets data and posts it to another receiving.php https page. My problems is whenever I submit my data for posting the receiving.php displays server error. I have read articles about cURL but I don't have a clear picture of the syntax.

user.php

```
<form action="https://www.mydomain.com/ssl/receiving.php"> 
<input type="text" name="variable" />
<input type="submit" name="buttonName" />
</form>
```

receving.php

```
if(isset($_POST["buttonName"]))
{
$variable=$_POST['variable'];

}
```

Comment: This is probably not related to HTTPS and most likely a bug in your receiving.php.

To get the data in the `$_POST` superglobal, add `method="POST"` to your `<form>` tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to add `method="POST"` to your `form` tag. By default it'll submit through GET. If that doesn't work, try `var_dump($_POST)` in receiving.php to see exactly what's coming through. cURL is mainly for when you want a script to make a request to a server on its own. A form submit shouldn't need to worry about cURL.

What error are you receiving though? This shouldn't display an error as your `isset()` should just return false.

Comment: Actually I am using mehtod="post" and I forgot to post that. But still everytime I post from user.php the receiving.php (https://p9.secure.hostingprod.com/@myDomain.org/ssl/receiving.php) outputs "server error"

Comment: Your link gives me a 404, can you link me to your user.php?

Comment: actually I have changed my website name to myDomain.org for security purposes..My question is how do you connect(posting data) from a secured https page to another secured https page, because both those pages are secured

Comment: The secure nature of this submit shouldn't be affecting you. That acts at a lower level than the form submit code, so you shouldn't need to modify your script to accommodate for this. If you're seeing errors it's likely in your receiving.php file. Are you getting any details on this error?

Comment: Yes, I have thought of that the problem is on the receving.php. Maybe there is a code added so that the submission of the form will not yield an error. The Error page details days " It may be down for maintenance or configured incorrectly." but I have configured the url correctly. Also when I click the address bar and press enter to submit again it return false that It doesn't recognize my if(isset($_POST["buttonName"]));

Comment: Modify your receiving.php file and add at the top `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` Let me know if that causes it to spit out useful errors.

Comment: Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent. Thanks for the reply. This is the error.

Comment: I have just made the session_start the first thing after the php opening and solved the problem. Thank you for all you replies.

Comment: Hey, no problem. Just know that almost anything involving the setting of cookies or sessions is going to need to be sent before any output is sent to the browser. As sending output to the browser makes PHP send the headers to the browser. It doesn't need to be first in the file, just before any output.

Comment: Thanks for the additional info.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use the $_GET method instead of $_POST because $_GET is a method that displays your request in the form in URL. while $_POST for security reason is just getting data from the form and not displaying the actions you've requested.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="https://www.mydomain.com/ssl/receiving.php">
```

if you want to use $_POST you need to make your form method set to `method="POST"` or by default your method form is using "GET".

So you instead of using `$_POST` , you need to use `$_GET` in your case.

Comment: Actually I am using mehtod="post" and I forgot to post that. But still everytime I post from user.php the receiving.php (p9.secure.hostingprod.com/@myDomain.org/ssl/receiving.php) outputs "server error" – user2658838